# Creating basic 3D Perspective Displacement model with PyGMT

Tags: visualization, pygmt

I am trying to create a 3D Perspective Displacement Map from a displacement image .tif file, however i am having trouble loading in the file/ confused as to the correct way to do it. I am trying to use the pygmt.load_dataarray method however i get an error saying that the file couldn't be found (I have ensured the path is correct). Is this the correct way to load in data from a .tif file? I have tried looking through the examples on the PyGMT docs however they all use datasets from the GMT server as opposed to local displacement map files so don't really solve my issues. Thanks in advance.

`

```
import pygmt

fig = pygmt.Figure()
grid_file = pygmt.load_dataarray('path/to/.tif file')

print(grid_file)
```

`
[image: Error Message Shown]